# Fraud detection using auto-encoders and Keras

Tags: classification, keras, class-imbalance, autoencoder

I am following [this example](https://medium.com/@curiousily/credit-card-fraud-detection-using-autoencoders-in-keras-tensorflow-for-hackers-part-vii-20e0c85301bd) to learn a bit about the use of auto-encoders in fraud detection.
Now that I reached the end of the article, two questions rose in mind:

1. Can we train the network in an unsupervised way, freeze the layers weights, add a sigmoid layer as an output then finally use this model as a binary classifier?
2. Are auto-encoders considered as the state-of-the-art method in fraud detection? What other alternatives can be used in this case?

Comment: Do layer-wise training like Hinton for Deep Belief Networks, and then train a classifier with the internal representation